# Regression function by weighted least squares using scikit-learn

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

I want to use `scikit-learn`'s [DecisionTreeRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor), but I need a different criterion.
Is there any way to make my own decision function? Rather than mean squared error, I need a to use a regression tree based on weighted least squares.

What would the best modification be? I'm thinking I would need to modify the tree to change the way `feature_importances_` are calculated.

However, I checked the [code of `tree.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py) and while it mentions `tree_.computer_feature_importances()`, I can't sem to find where to make any edits.

Comment: the [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.fit) function accepts `sample_weight` as an argument.

Comment: I understand that, but the decision tree regressor operates on *mean squared error*, whilst I need the decision function to be *least square error*. Will providing *sample_weight* array be enough? If so, how?

Comment: There's "mean square error" which is a metric of how good your line fits the data, and there's "method of least squares", which is a method to minimize (mean) square error. There's no such thing as "least square error".

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing the terms... but what's Weighted Least Squares? As in here:
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/wls.html
Is it then the "weighted version" of "method of least squares"?

Comment: I haven't dived too deep into the article, but yes, it looks like weighted least squares (WLS) are contrasted with ordinary least squares (OLS). Though I'm not sure it's possible to (easily) use alternative criterion (docs say "The only supported criterion is “mse”") and actually I don't see the point in it. What are you trying to do with a different criterion?

Comment: Concerning `feature_importance_`. It is a property that is not stored, but instead computed (just as you mentioned) with `tree_.compute_feature_importances()`, which is a Cython method in [`_tree.pyx`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L2509).

Comment: I'm trying to implement Algorithm 2 on page 5 of this paper: http://clgiles.ist.psu.edu/papers/SDM2007-boosting-active-learning.pdf, in particular step 2 (a). In fact I'm also trying to implement something similar, mentioned here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93691/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-a-regression-function-and-then-use-it-to-update-other, but stuck in understanding the concept of using regression functions.

Comment: I believe you need to learn about linear regression and how it works first. There's a very nice [course](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture) on machine learning from Andrew Ng, and second chapter is all about LR. Also, I would suggest starting with simpler models than weighted regression trees. Regression is one topic, decision trees are another, together with weighting and boosting they make quite complicated model.

Comment: You'll have to modify the Cython code to make the tree work with a custom criterion.